# CefSharp doesn't run in WIndows 7

Tags: .net, windows, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I have been struggle to run my C# winforms CefSharp on Windows 7. Everytime that I try to run it I have a error and the app doesn't open.

I tryed to run this example on client:

https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample

Here some things of what I understood so far:

- Windows 7 with visual studio 2013 the program works perfectly.
- It doesn't run in clients with Windows 7 with only .NetFramework Installed.
- The page above says that I need all theses files in app folder to run it. 
  I have all this files but icudtl.dll. I have icudtl.dat instead. (I think the wiki is not correct though)

https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Getting-Started#copying-dependencies

Anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: Can you give screenshot of the error?

Comment: My bad! I tryed to post some images into this post but it doesn't show!

http://alysonmelo.imgur.com/all/

Comment: @alysonsm just upload it to www.tinypic.com and share the link here

Comment: As you can see, there are two images. One of them shows the app running normally on SDK environment and the other you can see all the required files on the folder but I can't run it. The client pc has .netFramework 4.5 installed though.

Comment: @alysonsm still no images..try googling the error may be you can find some clues.

Comment: I tryed many things but with no success!

Comment: @Amitd
Take a look at this image:

http://tinypic.com/r/2eem1qb/8

Comment: Should I install something more than .net Framework to make it run normally?

Comment: @alysonsm pls click the more details button at the bottom of the dialog..and take a screenshot..or you can see the error in  Windows EventViewer.

Comment: Nearly eight years later was this - [End of support for Windows 7/8/8.1](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/discussions/4336): "*Google Chrome is ending support for Windows Windows 7/8/8.1. Version 109 will be the last version to support Windows 7/8/8.1.*". That certainly wasn't the issue here because CefSharp 110 only came out in February 2023, but future visitors might encounter this for the reason that I mention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A picture of the error details would be helpful (click the expand button on the Windows error dialog), otherwise I can only guess.

Guessing: you need to install VC 2012 Redistributable Package x86.

Comment: It works!!! I tryed to install Visual C++ 2013 Redistributable and It didn't work but with VC99 2012 worked perfectly. Thank you very much!!!