# Chromium embedded framework(CEF). could not load cefsharp.core.dll issue

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I am Using CEF(Chromium Embedded frame work) in my windows application. its working fine in my machine. but after it is installed in user machine, not working. not sure which file is missing. i hope i dont want to do anything with the code as its working locally.

Getting the below error for the users

[image]

using VS2015 - 
framework:4.5.2 - 
cefsharp dll :51.0.0.0

I also make sure required files are there after installation see below

https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Output-files-description-table-(Redistribution)

refered below links in my case not working

[CefSharp doesn't run in WIndows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30465386/cefsharp-doesnt-run-in-windows-7)

[Unable to deploy CefSharp application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34880125/unable-to-deploy-cefsharp-application)

https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/NuGet/Readme.txt#L16

wondering how its working in the visual studio installed system?.in few windows7  system its working and not working in same windows 7 with vs2015..???
 so is there any specific thing needs to be installed on users system.

Thanks

Dev

Comment: The error message suggest some sort of version mismatch. The only requirement is `VC++ 2013 x86/x64`. You can use https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample for testing.

Comment: thanks amaitland for your reply..

Answer (score 0):

After few research i have resolved the issue. while doing the setup project for release or installation.Apart from cefsharp dll we need to add few more supporting files explicitly.find the below images. First images is the checklist you should make sure these are added along. Second image shows how to add.

[image]

[image]

Thanks
Dev

Comment: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Output-files-description-table-%28Redistribution%29

Comment: You may want to [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) so the question is marked as resolved.

Comment: how to add cef.pak ?

Comment: u can download from https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Output-files-description-table-%28Redistribution%29   already mentioned by amaitland